# Hi, Can anyone help me to find any alternative of next_day function in Google's Bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

Ex in other db is :  SELECT NEXT_DAY(Current_date,'TUE');
This returns the 1st Tuesday after the current_date.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK), WEEK(TUESDAY))
```

Comment: Hey Thanks a lot Issuela. This is working perfect :) .

Comment: You're welcome! Happy to help :)